# Why is unity's RaycastHit2D contact point is slightly off

Tags: unity, raycasting

This is a small test I made, basically I have a simple `BoxCollider2D` that has the top surface aligned with the x axis. It's just a `1x1` cube placed at `(0, -0.5)`. Now when I cast a ray down from position `(0, 1)` I would expect the resulting `RaycastHit2D`'s contact point to be `(0, 0)` however when I log the contact point, it shows it is slightly over the actual surface at `(0, -2.384186E-07)`.

So the question is, why does this happen? Also, can it be fixed somehow (like tweaking settings or something)?

Comment: [Do the docs help](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D-defaultContactOffset.html)? But more importantly: why are you comparing floats to a precision less than one millionth in the first place? 32-bit floats don't have that precision to offer by the time you're even just 8 units away from the origin, so you're going to have a bad time if you need precision on these relative scales. A game physics engine might not be the right tool for the job if you need that precision, or, conversely, your current high-precision algorithm might not be the right tool for your game.

Comment: @DMGregory well modifying Physics2D.defaultContactOffset seems to have no effect on the result. Also I have done further tests and I keep getting all sorts of numbers that aren't even that small like 0.002... I understand your comment on the precision of floats (or even double FWIW), however I would expect such errors on more complicated values like having a 0.1 (which can't be accurately represented in floats), but this is a simple ray cast from (1, 0) towards (0, 0) what could possibly throw the math off when I'm using nice rounded values.

Comment: My suggestion was not to change the contact offset. Rather I was saying "small offsets are normal in game physics — if you're trying to do something where a small offset is a problem, you may want to examine why you are doing that thing at all, and figure out whether you can do it in a way such that small offsets are not a problem" — but I don't have enough context about what you're trying to accomplish to suggest a concrete fix for your specific game feature.

Comment: @DMGregory Well there isn't a specific feature I'm working on, I just noticed that it happens and wondered why. Initially I was working to fixing something but I realized this probably isn't the cause. Also I do indeed expect small errors, just not this way, if any of the objects were to be positioned in a weird place (with coordinates that aren't nicely rounded) or the ray was cast with a weird angle, I would just dismiss it as that "floating point precision artifacts" and the like, but something really tells me this is simple enough that it should output the correct result.